# Prove a limit of function

Tags: limits

So while learning for my exam I came across such task. I've got trouble figuring out how to even start this.

$ \lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{x^\alpha}{C^x} = 0$
where $\alpha$ is any Real number and C is a constant > 1

Can you guys give share some advice or show some similar proofs?

Comment: Do you know L'Hôpital's rule?

Comment: @columbus8myhw: L H will not help directly, as $\alpha$ is just a real number. You would need a trick- similar to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Note that it suffices to show that $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}\dfrac{x^n}{C^x}=0$ for all natural numbers $n$, as we can always choose an $n > \alpha$, and we will have:

$\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}\dfrac{x^{\alpha}}{C^x}\leq \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}\dfrac{x^n}{C^x}$.

Can you show the first limit is $0$?

Comment: Oh, I did not notice this fact.
And for the first limit, I've got some trouble with showing the limits using the definition, but I think I can try

Comment: I've just found a tip - tu use tha fact that for sequence $ \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{n^\alpha}{C^n} = 0$, does this one make sense?

Comment: @Andrew: That will also do it, for similar reason.